# How to restrict read only field on visualforce page to edit using Inline edit functionality

Tags: apex, fls

I have provided standard inline edit functionality on the visualforce page. I want to restrict the user to edit the field if he/she has not edit access on it. I have set FLS as read only for these fields. Still I can edit this field and able to save the new value. Standard contoller for the page is 'Account' and extention class is 'with sharing' keyword.

```
    <apex:page standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardController="Account" extensions="AMSocketController">
    </apex:page>
```

Apex Class is:

```
public with sharing class AMSocketController{
 //Constructor
    public AMSocketController(Apexpages.Standardcontroller stdController) {

}
```

}

How to restrict read only field on visualforce page to edit using Inline edit functionality?

Thank you In advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use apex:inputField only to apply FLS.

> VisualForce will also remove fields for which users do not have FLS
>   visibility when rendering edit pages. Additionally, all
>   apex:inputField tags will be rendered as read-only elements for fields
>   that are set to read-only through FLS. Please note that using other
>   input tags such as apex:inputText or apex:inputTextArea with SObject
>   fields indicate to VisualForce that the fields should not be treated
>   as SObject fields and prevent the platform to automatically enforcing
>   FLS.

Comment: I am facing the problem for this code :                                          <apex:outputField value="{!account.of_MDs_using_Coordinator_Core__c}">
                            <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick" showOnEdit="update"/>
                        </apex:outputField>

Comment: If you have restricted the field through FLS then page will show you error insufficient privilege while saving the record. Is it happening in your case ?

Comment: I was able to edit read-only field because of 'system admin' profile has system permission 'Edit Read Only Fields' and it is by default on.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two elements for a particular field for Example:

(This isVisible should be checked in the controller whether the user can edit or not)

```
<apex:outputField value="{!x.somefield__c}" rendered={!isVisible}/>

AND

<apex:inputFiled value="{!x.somefield__c}" rendered={!isVisible}/>
```